# Why shoud I use resource instead of route?

Tags: ember.js

It seems that the only difference between using `resource` and `route` is the naming inheritance since both of them support route nesting.

Any other reasons why `resource` is still in [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sam Selikoff argues in [Future-proofing your Ember 1.x code](https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97):

> Use `this.route` instead of `this.resource` in Router.map

Mitch Lloyd presents [some reasons](https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97#comment-1338411) in favour of `resource` over `route`, mostly that the former reset the namespace, which he suggests makes for

- simpler directory structure
- simpler `link-to` paths

For more discussion on this, see the Gist thread.

It’s unclear to me whether `resource` routes are actually disappearing in Ember 2.0, I can’t find official mention of it.

Comment: Thanks for the gist, just what I was looking for.